# Mathematical Moddeling of Elastic Robots

Tags: kinematics, simulator, dynamics

We can easily compute the rigid robot kinematics and dynamics. There is many resources, simulators and modelling tools about it. But i couldnt find any of these for elastic robots. Can you suggest resources and modelling tools?

Comment: I'm sure a librarian at your local university could help you find some great resources, but there is no problem here for us to solve - you're just asking for shopping recommendations.

Comment: "Elastic Robots" is a fairly broad term. Perhaps I can suggest that you search for published papers involving the modelling and control of "flexible link" and "flexible joint" mechanisms and have a look at the problem the authors are trying to solve, it may provide a more concrete starting point? Let us know whether or not this is a closer refinement of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Finite Element Anlysis (FEA) tools like [Abaqus](http://www.3ds.com/products-services/simulia/products/abaqus/). Also please look [this paper](http://www.ece.msstate.edu/research/robotics/wiki_media/publications/2010/IJRR/Design_and_Kinematic_Modeling_of_Constant_Curvature_Continuum_Robots_-_A_Review.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

You should use multi body simulation https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multibody_system. There is also modelling software for this. Finite elements are more for structural verification.

For modelling, you could use python's pydy module: https://www.pydy.org/. There are also other open source software tools: http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~trink/sim_packages.html.

Answer (score 0):

I think the vast majority of compliant or "elastic" robots you will find have rigid links, but compliant joints.  I believe robots with flexible links is still a topic of active research.  So your best bet is to look through academic papers.  It is not a simple solution.  I found some old papers to get you started:

- [Control Of Flexible Robot Arm](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.14.1578) by J.D. Lee, L. S. Hayna, Ben Li Wang, and KwangHornp Tsai.
- Havlik, S., "Structural compliance of flexible robot arms: analysis, synthesis and control aspects," Advanced Robotics, 1991. 'Robots in Unstructured Environments', 91 ICAR., Fifth International Conference on , vol., no., pp.1622,1625 vol.2, 19-22 June 1991